# Select all layers within marquee tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2014, mac

I want to select multiple layers within a marquee selection.

For example, I want to select, copy and paste the tan background and black squiggle which are on two separate layers:

[image]

Comment: Reason for downvote? I was very clear and concise with my question

Comment: You were most likely downvoted because you didn't say what you attempted, combined with how rudimentary this is. I'm not the one who downvoted you but that would be my best guess.

Answer (score 2):

`Edit > Copy Merged` (<kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) -- This will copy what you see. It will *not* retain layer structure.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Move(v)** tool in Photoshop you can select multiple layers. Hold Ctrl+ drag move tool to select multiple layers in PS.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This would move the whole layer, though. Not just the selection.

Comment: Zoom-out with Ctrl - , so that you could see whole document fit to canvas. from outside canvas, using move tool drag over the elements to select. corresponding layers will get selected.

Comment: Thx! What I was looking for was to select layers by clicking on them in the image. Worked perfectly with holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Move tool
2. Enable Auto select from corner
3. Zoom out and put the mouse pointer outside the canvas
4. Drag and you'll see a marquee, drag more to cover the layers you want to select.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to select layers by marquee in the latest versions Photoshop. Although, I wonder if the same effect can be achieved if the selection has to be inside the canvas, or with a more complicated selection (e.g. lasso).

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread, I know, but none of the answers given hit the nail for me, so I'm providing the best solution I found.

In my case, I needed to select lots of different layers placed around the same area, without merging them.

I found that holding down Lctrl while dragging the marquee tool over the layers, automatically selects them.

No need to click on them individually.